# Is it possible to have the enum ordinal in kotlin without explicitly calling ordinal?

Tags: enums, kotlin

In C enums are all numeric and you can reference the value just by the name.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum week { sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };

int main()
{
    enum week today;
    today = wednesday;
    printf("Day %d",today+1);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs: day 4

---

In Kotlin I would like something similar, at least being able to get rid of the `.ordinal`.

Currently it's like this:

```
enum class Week { sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday }
```

and to access an element I have to use the verbose `Week.monday.ordinal`

Comment: Are you only using the constants for numbers?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is [overloading the unary + operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) so that you can use `+Week.sunday`, but I'm not sure if that's what you want

Comment: @jrtapsell yes only for numbers, just like in C. Numbers are from 0 to N.

Comment: @user5507535 What are you trying to use it for, there may be better ways to achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically answer by [@jrtapsell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8041461/jrtapsell) is great and full. But also in kotlin you can override **invoke()** operator.

```
enum class Weekday { MONDAY, TUESDAY;

    operator fun invoke(): Int {
       return ordinal
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("${Weekday.TUESDAY() + 1}")
}
```

Result: 2

AFM it is much prettier.

Answer (score 3):

## Overriding operators

Demo code:

```
enum class WeekDay {
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY;

    companion object: Iterable<WeekDay> {
        override fun iterator() = values().iterator()
    }


    operator fun unaryPlus() = ordinal
    operator fun not() = ordinal
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for (day in WeekDay) {
        println("$day ${!day} ${+day}")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MONDAY 0 0
TUESDAY 1 1
WEDNESDAY 2 2
THURSDAY 3 3
FRIDAY 4 4
SATURDAY 5 5
SUNDAY 6 6
```

This shows how to use unary operators to get the ordinals, I have included 2 examples:

- unaryPlus

  - This overrides the + operator, which I use as `+day`
- not

  - This overrides the ! operator, which I use as `!day`

## Using extension functions

You can create an extension function which calls the function you want to call, but gets the ordinal from the passed value. This would make the call like this:

- Using code

  - Extension function (Enum member)

    - Target method (Ordinal)